# Importing other python packages in __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, python-import

I would like to know if importing packages like pandas or NumPy, which can be the basic need for many modules of a package, should be imported in **init**.py? If not, can anyone please tell how they should be imported, rather than importing them in each module of a package?

Comment: `__init__.py` is for importing your *own* packages. It doesn't affect the packages imported into those files. Just import `numpy` et al in every file that needs them. There's no special trick.

Comment: Doesn't that create pandas instance for all modules? Also, if suppose I have to load spacy's large model, then also, would this be the recommendation?

Comment: No, Python is smart enough to only load the module on the first `import` statement. Redundant imports just bring the existing names into scope

Answer (score 1):

No, you should import them in each python file you need them in.
The **init** is used, when you want to use your module in another project and want want to make the modules classes, functions, etc. available for outside the module